# Caliburn Export Trigger Value is null

Tags: c#, xaml

So I implemented a trigger on my xaml page to point to my Export Function. But it's passing a null value instead of the grid value. If I can get help please.

xaml.cs

```
<Button Content="Spreadsheet Export" Style="{StaticResource ActionButtonStyle}">
     <i:Interaction.Triggers>
           <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
               <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="Export">
                  <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding ElementName=Grid}" />
               </cal:ActionMessage>
            </i:EventTrigger>
     </i:Interaction.Triggers>
 </Button>
```

The Export Function:

```
public void Export(RadGridView grid)
{
    var dialog = new SaveFileDialog()
    {
        DefaultExt = "xls", FilterIndex = 1,
        Filter = "Excel files (*.xls)|*.xls|All files|*.*",
    };
    if (! (bool) dialog.ShowDialog()) return;
    using (var stream = dialog.OpenFile())
    {
        grid.Export(stream, new GridViewExportOptions()
        {
            Format = ExportFormat.ExcelML, ShowColumnHeaders = true,
            ShowColumnFooters = true, ShowGroupFooters = false,
        });
    }
 }

<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="Grid" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, IsAsync=True}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ShowColumnFooters="True">
```

all Xaml code within the same xaml.cs file

Comment: Can you show the element named "Grid" and how it relates to the button, i.e. are they both in the same panel? Same UserControl?

Comment: Updated, if you need anything else please let me know. Have been quite puzzled with this.